# CakePHP Development of frontend/backend application

Tags: php, cakephp

I have to develop frontend/backend application using cakephp.

can you give me advice how should i develop them, using same cakephp library?

or I have to develop them using separate cakephp libraries?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer this question - it is way too broad. I suggest you head over to the CakePHP website and take a look at the sample applications and tutorials offered there.

Answer (score 3):

I am confused - cakePHP would be used to implement both.

PHP would be used to implement the server-side backend. The same "project" would also contain HTML, JS, CSS, etc that will be used to render the front-end within the browser. Any PHP "views" will also execute code on the back-end, although any HTML output will be rendered on the frontend.

Does that help at all? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If by frontend/backend, you mean an application with a user interface (frontend) and an administration interface (backend), then you want to refer to the [Prefix Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) section of the manual. This will allow you to have separate flow and interfaces (controller/view) for each type of user while sharing the same data (models).

If by frontend/backend, you mean an application (frontend) that communicates with another server application (backend) using web services, then you want to look at the [Additional Class Paths](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#additional-class-paths) section of the manual. This will allow you to share common classes with two (or more) separate applications.

Note: the above links are for CakePHP 3.x, though these features have existed in one form or another since v1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if I understood you correct, but if I did:

You can set up multiple projects using the same cake-core files. The core files don't even need to be placed in the webroot folder..

http://book.cakephp.org/view/35/Advanced-Installation

Answer (score 1):

For your own sanity, you should regard the backend management as part of the same project as the frontend.

The systems I have built generally use view-type methods for the public view and crud-type methods for the admin view. How you lock down the admin is your choice. Personally I don't like the default admin prefix way. I use login and ACL - Mark Story's [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/641/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application) on http://book.cakephp.org/ is superb. With that you can password protect methods.

CakePHP is very flexible and extensible and you can make the administration as simple or as flexible as you like.

Comment: Also see Mark Story's blog: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-1

Comment: i was not so clear with my question... 

for frontend, i would like to have ulr like: http://myapp.com, and for backend http://myapp.com/admin


do i need to have separate cakephp libraries, or i can use same for both?

Comment: In that case look at http://book.cakephp.org/view/544/Prefix-Routing which will do just that, although you can also achieve what you want using routes.php or .htaccess or both.

Comment: "do i need to have separate cakephp libraries, or i can use same for both?"

No. You just need one CakePHP installation, i.e. one cake directory and, of course, you'll use the same database.